# Access Twitter using Swift

Tags: swift, twitter, oauth

I'm using the Swifter library to access Twitter in my Swift iOS 8 app: https://github.com/mattdonnelly/Swifter. The problem is that I'm getting a 401 Not Authorized error from Twitter. I double checked any possible reasons for this:

1. Consumer key/secret is wrong
2. Make sure not to use API v1 (use 1.1)

With both these problems fixed (according to the Twitter docs), I'm still faced with this issue. I'm thinking it has something to do with how I authenticate. I'm trying to access a public feed without using ACAccount on the device.

Here is my code:

```
// MARK: Twitter
    var swifter: Swifter

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.swifter = Swifter(consumerKey: "KEY", consumerSecret: "SECRET")
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    func getTwitterTimeline() {
        let failureHandler: ((NSError) -> Void) = {
            error in
            self.alertWithTitle("Error", message: error.localizedDescription)
        }

        self.swifter.getStatusesUserTimelineWithUserID("erhsannounce", count: 20, sinceID: nil, maxID: nil, trimUser: true, contributorDetails: false, includeEntities: true, success: {
            (statuses: [JSONValue]?) in

            if statuses != nil {
                self.tweets = statuses!
            }

        }, failure: failureHandler)
    }

    func alertWithTitle(title: String, message: String) {
        var alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

**UPDATE:** I've been working on the app, trying to achieve the functionality of using App only (not user based) auth and access token to read a public timeline.

I updated the code to use an access token and app only auth. Still not working though.

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        let accessToken = SwifterCredential.OAuthAccessToken(key: "KEY", secret: "SECRET")
        let credential = SwifterCredential(accessToken: accessToken)

        self.swifter = Swifter(consumerKey: "cKEY", consumerSecret: "cSECRET", appOnly: true)
        swifter.client.credential = credential
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update 02-03-2015

You need to authenticate with the server using App Only Authentication rather than passing in an OAuth Token.

As well as this, you are also not requesting status' with userId correctly as you are passing in the user's screen name. You need to obtain the user id with the username and then request for status'.

The complete working code is below:

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.swifter = Swifter(consumerKey: "cKEY", consumerSecret: "cSECRET", appOnly: true)
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    self.swifter.authorizeAppOnlyWithSuccess({ (accessToken, response) -> Void in
        self.twitterIsAuthenticated = true
    }, failure: { (error) -> Void in
        println("Error Authenticating: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    })
}

@IBAction func getUserButtonPressed(sender: UIButton?) {
    if (self.twitterIsAuthenticated) {
        self.getTwitterUserWithName("erhsannounce")
    } else {
        // Authenticate twitter again.
    }
}

func getTwitterUserWithName(userName: String) {
    self.swifter.getUsersShowWithScreenName(userName, includeEntities: true, success: { (user) -> Void in
        if let userDict = user {
            if let userId = userDict["id_str"] {
                self.getTwitterStatusWithUserId(userId.string!)
            }
        }
        }, failure: failureHandler)
}

func getTwitterStatusWithUserId(idString: String) {
    let failureHandler: ((error: NSError) -> Void) = {
        error in
        println("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    self.swifter.getStatusesUserTimelineWithUserID(idString, count: 20, sinceID: nil, maxID: nil, trimUser: true, contributorDetails: false, includeEntities: true, success: {
        (statuses: [JSONValue]?) in

        if statuses != nil {
            self.tweets = statuses
        }

        }, failure: failureHandler)
}
```

---

It looks as though you are not Authenticating with the server.

From your code I can see you are using OAuth authentication initialisation but are failing to call the authenticate function.

```
swifter.authorizeWithCallbackURL(callbackURL, success: {
    (accessToken: SwifterCredential.OAuthAccessToken?, response: NSURLResponse) in

    // Handle success

    },
    failure: {
        (error: NSError) in

        // Handle Failure

    })
```

Add this in and then call your getTwitterTimeline() afterwards.

I hope this helps

Comment: This worked perfectly for making Swifter access Twitter, but I'm having an issue with how it does so. I'm trying to read a public timeline using Twitter, and so I don't want there to be a need for authentication by the end user. This method requires the user to sign in. Any ideas?

Comment: @ShaanSingh Could you let me know the error you get in the Failure handler?

Comment: Sure thing. It's error HTTP Status 401: Unauthorized, Response: Failed to validate oauth signature and token. (and thanks for the help by the way!)

Comment: Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I will show how to (in 2021) not need to sign in every time. Please follow these steps (replace YOURAPPNAME with whatever your app name is):

1. add YOURAPPNAME:// as a callback URL on the twitter developer portal, under authentication settings. To do this, you need to enable 3-legged OAuth, and add this in the callback URLS. You also need to enter a website URL, but it can be anything (i have https://www.google.com). Also make sure (if you want to tweet) that **YOU CHANGE APP PERMISSIONS TO READ AND WRITE** in settings.
2. in your podfile, make sure you have the line:

```
pod 'Swifter' , :git => 'https://github.com/mattdonnelly/Swifter.git'
```

DO NOT just use pod 'Swifter' because there is another project called Swifter that is not by mattdonnelly and will not work.

3. Click on your project in the Project Explorer, select the info tab. At the bottom you will see URL Types. Expand it and click the plus sign. In the URL Schemes enter YOURAPPNAME (if your app name is "demoApp" enter demoApp not demoApp://
4. If your app delegate isnt already using the open url function (standard is no but mine was because i have google sign in, in my case i dont need to do anything) in your app delegate **import Swifter** and add this function:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        
    Swifter.handleOpenURL(url, callbackURL: URL(string: "YOURAPPNAME://")!)
        
    return true
}
```

5. in your view controller, you need to first authorize twitter, and then you can do whatever (tweet, lookup feeds, etc.). You can do this with swifter.authorize, which opens a brower. For those looking to not need this after the first time, that is where the swifter.verifyAccountCredentials comes in. To find CONSUMER_KEY and CONSUMER_SECRET go to the keys and tokens area of the twitter developer portal.

```
import Swifter
import AuthenticationServices

class ViewController: UIViewController, ASWebAuthenticationPresentationContextProviding {
    func presentationAnchor(for session: ASWebAuthenticationSession) -> ASPresentationAnchor {
        return self.view.window!
    }
    
    var swifter: Swifter!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "twitterOAuthToken") == nil {
            swifter = Swifter(consumerKey: CONSUMER_KEY, consumerSecret: CONSUMER_SECRET)
            if let url = URL(string: "YOURAPPNAME://") {
                swifter.authorize(withProvider: self, callbackURL: url) { (token, response) in
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(token?.key, forKey: "twitterOAuthToken")
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(token?.secret, forKey: "twitterOAuthSecret")
                    print("signed in!!")
                }
            }
            
        } else {
            swifter = Swifter(consumerKey: CONSUMER_KEY, consumerSecret: CONSUMER_SECRET, oauthToken: UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "twitterOAuthToken") ?? "", oauthTokenSecret: UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "twitterOAuthSecret") ?? "")
            swifter.verifyAccountCredentials(includeEntities: nil, skipStatus: nil, includeEmail: nil) { (json) in
                print("signed in!")
            } failure: { (error) in
                self.swifter = Swifter(consumerKey: CONSUMER_KEY, consumerSecret: CONSUMER_SECRET)
                if let url = URL(string: "YOURAPPNAME://") {
                    self.swifter.authorize(withProvider: self, callbackURL: url) { (token, response) in
                        UserDefaults.standard.set(token?.key, forKey: "twitterOAuthToken")
                        UserDefaults.standard.set(token?.secret, forKey: "twitterOAuthSecret")
                        print("signed in!!")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        
        
       let button = UIButton()
        button.layer.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8078431487, green: 0.02745098062, blue: 0.3333333433, alpha: 1)
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 200, y:0, width: 200, height: 200)
        button.center = view.center
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tweet), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(button)

    }
    
    @objc func tweet() {
        swifter.postTweet(status: "wild") { (json) in
            print("tweeted!")
        } failure: { (error) in
            print("tweet failed")
        }
    }
}
```