# How does one force the "openURL url: NSURL!" version of AppDelegate.application() to be called in a Swift 1.2 app?

Tags: ios, swift, oauth

Question re-edited following some research, problem now as stated in title (specifically this is for use with [the Swifter framework](https://github.com/mattdonnelly/Swifter)). I have:

a. a single-page XCode 6.3 Beta iPhone project;

b. in which I have added a *URL Type* to *CFBundleURLTypes* in *Info.plist* (via the *Info* tab in the project's settings), which looks like this:

```
    ...
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>com.example.SwifterTest4</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>swifter</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    ...
```

c. AppDelegate.swift coded thus:

```
import SwifteriOS
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate
{
    var window: UIWindow?

    func application ( application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject? ) -> Bool
    {
        println( "application() openURL: " + url.absoluteString! );
        Swifter.handleOpenURL( url )
        return true
    }
}
```

d. and ViewController.swift coded thus:

```
import SwifteriOS
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    var swifter: Swifter

    required init ( coder aDecoder: NSCoder )
    {
        let oauthToken: String = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("oauth_token") as! String
        let oauthTokenSecret: String  = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("oauth_secret") as! String

        // these two actually contain useful values
        let consumerKey = "my-consumer-key"
        let consumerSecret = "my-consumer-secret"

        self.swifter = Swifter( consumerKey: consumerKey, consumerSecret: consumerSecret, oauthToken: oauthToken, oauthTokenSecret: oauthTokenSecret )

        super.init( coder: aDecoder )
    }

    override func viewDidLoad ()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        swifter.authorizeWithCallbackURL( NSURL( string: "swifter://success" )!,
        success:
        {
            ( accessToken: SwifterCredential.OAuthAccessToken?, response: NSURLResponse ) in
            println( "SUCCESS" )
        },
        failure: 
        {
            ( error: NSError ) in
            println( "FAILURE" )
        })
    }
}
```

The `application( ... )` func in AppDelegate is not being called, whereas the *Registering Custom URL Schemes* section of [this official Apple documentation page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html), and [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28005919/how-to-authorize-twitter-with-swifter) suggest that the addition of a `CFBundleTypeRole` in `Info.plist` is sufficient to force the call. It seems not though.

With reference to @rmaddy's comment below, I have also tried this is stable release XCode 6.2 to no avail either, although even if that did work it wouldn't be that useful, because [the Swifter framework](https://github.com/mattdonnelly/Swifter) has been updated to Swift 1.2 in the past week. Without the call to `application( ... )` [presumably], a `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` is thrown at `let oauthToken: String` in `ViewController.init()`. Alternatively, if `oauthToken` and `oauthTokenSecret` are simply omitted, `FAILURE` is printed to the console.

I would be grateful of any help, thank you.

Comment: FYI - upgrade to the release version of Xcode.

Comment: Right. Beta versions are sometimes not so hot, check. Thanks @rmaddy. Time to climb back up that old pyramid of doom...

Comment: For now I am going to skip OAuth and use AppOnly auth just so I don't have to sit here pointlessly all day. Detailed in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28734678/access-twitter-using-swift